# Loopback component storage aws s3 ACL Permissions

Tags: amazon-s3, permissions, storage, acl, loopback

I'm working on this project and I've managed to upload an image through an end-point I created on my loopback model, the problem is I need the uploaded image to be publicly accessible and can't seem to find where to do that.
I've tried using the aws sdk to change the object permissions with putObjectACL but couldn't make it work, it said that I have build incorrectly the xml, since I can't even figure how to fill the properties that the method requires, so I found a way to change it and is to copy it and set the ACL to 'public-read' and then delete the original, then copying it again to it's original filename and delete again the other copy, seems like a pretty naughty solution, and I'm pretty sure there must be a more neat way to do it.
I do the upload with my remote method like this:

```
Container.upload(req,res,{container: "my-s3-bucket"},function(err,uploadInfo) { ... }
```

Container is my model connected to aws s3. And then I do the permission change like this (copying and deleting):

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({accessKeyId:"my-key-id",secretAccessKey:"my-key", region:"us-east-1"});

var s3 = new AWS.S3();
s3.copyObject( {
          Bucket:'my-s3-bucket',
          CopySource: 'my-s3-bucket/'+filename,
          Key: filename+"1",
          ACL: 'public-read'
        }, function(err,info) {
          if (err) return cb(err);

          s3.deleteObject( {
            Bucket:'my-s3-bucket',
            Key:filename
          }, function(err,info) {
            if (err) return cb(err);

            s3.copyObject( {
              Bucket: 'my-s3-bucket',
              CopySource: 'my-s3-bucket/'+filename+"1",
              Key: filename,
              ACL: 'public-read'
            }, function(err,info) {
              if (err) return cb(err);

              s3.deleteObject( {
                Bucket: 'my-s3-bucket',
                Key: my-s3-bucket+"1"
              }, function(err,info) {
                if (err) return cb(err);

                cb(null,uploadInfo);
              })
            })
          })
        });
```

I wonder if there is something more clean like this:

```
Container.upload(req,res,{container: "my-s3-bucket", ACL:'public-read'},function(err,uploadInfo) { ... }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5):

Sorry this comes a little late but the answer is in here:

https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-component-storage/pull/47

They added support for applying acls and some other stuff:

```
var dsImage = loopback.createDataSource({
   connector: require('loopback-component-storage'),
   provider: 'filesystem',
   root: path.join(__dirname, 'images'),

   getFilename: function(fileInfo) {
     return 'image-' + fileInfo.name;
   },
   acl: 'public-read',
   allowedContentTypes: ['image/png', 'image/jpeg'],
   maxFileSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024
 });
```

Putting that acl to 'public-read', does the trick.

Comment: This is awesome. Can we set `cache-control` header for the image in the same way?

Answer (score 1):

So in the end I had to discard the whole loopback component storage, and since I also needed to get some extra params aside from the file, I parsed the form with formidable and upload the file directly with the aws sdk, like this:

```
var formidable = require('formidable');

var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

form.parse(req, function(err,fields,files) {
  if (err) return cb(err);

  var fs = require('fs');
  var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

  AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId:"my-key-id",
    secretAccessKey:"my-key",
    region:"us-east-1"
  });

  var s3 = new AWS.S3();

  s3.putObject({
    Bucket:'shopika',
    Key: files.file.name,
    ACL:'public-read', //Public plz T^T
    Body: fs.createReadStream(files.file.path),
    ContentType:files.file.type
  }, function(err,data) {
    if (err) return cb(err);

  //Upload success, now I have the params I wanted in 'fields' and do my stuff with them :P
    cb(null,data);
  });
});
```